# Angular-4 min.js/.js file not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am trying to use js in angular 4 and I copy/past all the required js files in assets folder but min.js files goes under js files, I don't know why? so my scripts failed to load and progress bar not working, there is no error on browser console, can anyone tell what to do?
Here is index.html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>RevDashboard</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Reviews AI! | </title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="assets/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link href="assets/vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- NProgress -->
  <link href="assets/vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- iCheck -->
  <link href="assets/vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
  <link href="assets/build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body class="nav-md">
  <app-root></app-root>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="assets/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script src="assets/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- FastClick -->
  <script src="assets/vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
  <!-- NProgress -->
  <script src="assets/vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>
  <!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
  <script src="assets/vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
  <script src="assets/build/js/custom.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code where I use progress bar

```
<td class="project_progress">
 <div class="progress progress_sm">
 <div class="progress-bar bg-green" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="57"></div>
 </div>
 <small>57% Complete</small>
```

There is the images of file:
[image]

Here is the page Image
[image]

Comment: Can you try to load js files in the head tag?

Comment: Yes, I also tried that.

Comment: So, you are not using any dependency management tool like requireJS right ?

Comment: This is something your IDE/editor does visually to reduce the amount of files you see in your project structure (keeps it less cluttered). really your custom.css & custom.min.css are siblings in your css directory. The scripts don't load at all in your networks tab?